# Editing files from Ubuntu WSL directly from folder

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

by using the command "explorer.exe ." in the Windows Ubuntu WSL terminal it opens the folder which contains all the files of your Windows Subsystem, my question is: Can I use a program installed on Windows like VScode for example and edit a file from the Subsystem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accessing files in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is *officially* supported
from Windows 10 version 1903 (May 2019). Upgrade Windows 10 before doing this.
In older Windows 10 versions, creating and changing Linux files from Windows
resulted in [losing files or corrupting data](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

First, the installed distribution must be started (or initialized) before
accessing its files. Because in WSL side, the `/init` binary implements a
[Plan 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) server and without the server running, WSL files can't be accessed.
Here are the various ways to access WSL Linux distributions files:

- From WSL, run `explorer.exe .` command to open WSL files in File Explorer.
  This will open a File Explorer window, showing the files located inside of your
  Linux distribution’s filesystem. From here normal edit, copy and paste works.

[image: wsl-distro-home-folder]

- From Windows, the WSL distribution file system is mounted in `\\wsl$\`
  network path. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type that path.
  All running distribution will be shown as separate folders. Open those to use.

[image: mounted-network-drives]

- Also each network path (that is each mounted filesystem) can be mounted as a
  separate drive. Right click on the distribution folder name and choose
  'Map network drive...' > Choose driver letter (default is `Z:\`).

[image: mounted-as-a-separate-drive]

### Further Readings:

- [Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)
- [What’s new for WSL in Windows 10 version 1903?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/)