# Where are config files located in WSL?

Tags: linux, windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024114/location-of-ini-config-files-in-linux-unix) global/system config files are generally stored under `/etc` in linux. Is this also the case for WSL? If so where is the `/etc` equivalent directory located, as I was unable to find it in the WSL installation directory shown below:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc
```

**Read the warning** by @josh3736 in the answers below and don't make the mistake I made. Look at [this](https://superuser.com/a/1482152/996910) to edit WSL files correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found my `etc` folder in:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\etc
```

Note: I'm using WSL1 so as to be able to use VMware. WSL2 uses Hyper-V
which is incompatible with other virtualization hypervisors.
(*Edit: This is no longer true.*)

However, this is changing now and in the near future.
Recently both VirtualBox and VMware have released versions that support
Hyper-V and WSL2. You can learn more about it for
[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.0)
and
[VMware](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/01/vmware-workstation-tech-preview-20h1.html).
The VMware solution requires the soon to be released
[Windows 10 Build 20H1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/at-home/whats-new-wip-at-home-20h1), while VirtualBox is possibly
usable now.

This next version of Windows is also advertised as allowing greater
integration between Windows and WSL, perhaps even solving the problem
of concurrent updates of the same files from both subsystems.

Comment: This does not work with WSL 2. There, the whole disk is located in a single file.

Comment: @dan1st: WSL2 at the moment is a bit of a mess in that respect. The Windows/Linux interface supposedly will be improved in the next major Windows version. You can read all about the problem in bug report #4260 [WSL2: can't access linux file system from windows](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4260).

Comment: I use WSL2 since about half a year and had no problems.

Comment: @dan1st: Some have and some haven't and this can change very suddenly. Read the bug report.

Comment: Please edit in at least a note that these files should not be edited directly via those paths.

Comment: @Bob: That depends on how the updates are done. Many of these files are intended to be updated by the user. The next version of Windows supposedly will allow dual updates of the same files from both Windows and Linux without problem.

Answer (score 33):

**Warning: do *not* edit WSL files on disk from Windows.**

The files stored on disk in `%LocalAppData%\Packages` use special NTFS features to implement POSIX functionality/metadata (eg Linux permissions).  Using standard Windows tools/apps to edit these files will corrupt your Linux environment.

Instead, WSL provides a mount that allows you to safely access and edit files inside your Linux environment.  It is available under `\\wsl$\`.

See [Do Not Change Linux Files Using Windows Apps and Tools](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Comment: If we can't edit WSL files directly from a host NTFS volume why isn't WSL just using a VHD/VHDX? Seems weird to expose the files if we can't do anything with them...